# Доступ к элементам из фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-fragment

Хочу при открытии фрагмента считать данные из БД и добавить их в ListView. Данные считываются, судя по отладке они добавляются в ListView, но на экране не отображаются. Также не получается изменить текст в TextView.

Код во фрагменте:

```
package apk.fridge.ru.fridge;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import DBSetup.DBAssetHelper;

public class FragmentAllIngredients extends Fragment {

    View view;
    Context context;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_ingredients, null);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        DBAssetHelper dbSetup = new DBAssetHelper(context);
        dbSetup.getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] columns = {DBOpenHelper.TableAllIngredientsColumnName};
            Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.TableAllIngredients, columns, null, null, null, null, DBOpenHelper.TableAllIngredientsColumnName);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String[] ingredients = new String[cursor.getCount()];
                int i = 0;
                do {
                    ingredients[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                    i++;
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
                ListView lviAllIngredients = view.findViewById(R.id.lvi_allIngredients);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ingredients);
                lviAllIngredients.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "База данных недоступна" + '\n' + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_ingredients, container, false);
    }
}
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_ingredients, container, false)` возвращает новую `View`, а не ту которую вы создали в начале метода `onCreateView`, Вам нужно заменить даную строку на `return view;`